# How to optimise the code evaluation in Selenium with Python

Tags: python, performance, selenium

I would like to extract the span text located within the **class** `SOME_CLASS_NAME`. The  **class** `SOME_CLASS_NAME` might not always available. Also, it take some time before the class properly visible if it does exist.

To handle this, the following code were propsed.

## Dirty workaround to check whether the class available or not

```
size_len = WebDriverWait(self.browser, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
                    (By.XPATH, './/span[@class = "SOME_CLASS_NAME"]')))
```

OR

```
 if len( self.browser.find_elements_by_xpath('.//span[@class = "SOME_CLASS_NAME"]') ) > 0 :  
        element =self.browser.find_elements_by_xpath( './/span[@class = "SOME_CLASS_NAME"]' )[ 0 ].text
    
 else:
         element = '0'
```

While the above approach work, but,I found it very inefficient to evaluate the class for 3 times.

May I know if there is a way to make the above code more efficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use try..except block and use `visibility_of_element_located`() instead `presence_of_element_located`()

```
try:
    print(WebDriverWait(self.browser, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, './/span[@class = "SOME_CLASS_NAME"]'))).text)
except:
    print("element no available")
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Should the TimeoutException: be there? or this is some special case?

Comment: @balandongiv : You can use ` except TimeoutException:` If you want but with that you can't continue further.if you want continue to the next step then use except.